# aria strategy for list items with an action

Tags: html, wai-aria

I need to create a list of items, each item does two things.

1. It contains a button that triggers a button that adds the item to the user's "favorites".
2. But also, when the user clicks the item (and not the button inside the item),
   then the user is redirected to the item's description page.
   In other words, the list item itself is a link.

I'm trying to think about the keyboard navigation accessibility wise, but I'm
not sure about the strategy to implement.

Basically my problem is this:

- If tab tabs to the next list item, and space triggers the link (not the button),
      then how does the user click the button?
- If tab tabs the list item's link first, then the list item's button in second,
      then focuses the next item and so on...
      Then, it's a lot of (unneccessary) tabbing!

What stragegy would you use/should be used?

Here is my html markup (without aria semantics for now), but
I'm not even sure if that's the best markup for the situation.
If you have any suggestion please help.

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="#">item 1</a>
        <button>add item 1 to my favourites</button>            
    </li>
</ul>
```

Actually, I've an idea, but it might just work for this special case:
- the tabs navigates the list items, and once an item has focus, the left and right arrows can focus further either the link or the button.

(
Unfortunately, my layout has also a grid mode which presents the same items but in a flexbox grid, and it probably makes more sense, when in grid mode, to have the arrows navigate through the list items, but that's another problem...
)

Comment: You can not put a button into a link, that is invalid HTML. Make them two separate elements, and then _position_ one over the other. Make sure to include enough click-/touchable area (usually padding) on the smaller one that's on top, and proper focus styles, for accessibility.

Comment: thanks, I forgot about that.